# Bootstrap's tooltips require Popper.js

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, popper.js

I use Bootstrap 4 and Jquery-3.3.1 in my project.
I use js as follows:

```
 <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/umd/popper.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

When the page loads, I have the following errors:

```
SyntaxError: export declarations may only appear at top level of a module   -----  popper.min.js:4:19633

TypeError: Bootstrap's tooltips require Popper.js (https://popper.js.org/) ------ bootstrap.min.js:6:34702
```

And these warnings also give:

```
Source map error: request failed with status 404
Resource URL: http://sitename.com/Content/bootstrap.css
Source Map URL: bootstrap.css.map

Source map error: request failed with status 404
Resource URL: http://sitename.com/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js
Source Map URL: bootstrap.min.js.map
```

please guide me

Answer (score 27):

I had the same problem. I just imported Popper.js before Bootstrap.min.js. Now it's working.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you're trying to use local imports for these scripts, which might simply mean that your popper.min.js file isn't in the proper directory.  If this is not the case, I would simply use CDN (Content Delivery Network) imports for these scripts instead, as it is much simpler to work with.  For example:

```
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Popper JS -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you.
By replacing the links you provided, it's true, but the problem is that the program might run on a system that does not have the Internet.
How can I download the downloaded version without problems?

Comment: (Sorry for the slow response, things got busy)  I'm not entirely familiar with the syntax you are using for the src attribute in your code, but in past projects, I have used syntax like: `<script src="jquery-min.js"></script>` to include locally present resources with no problems.

Answer (score 4):

to use popper locally  (offline) download de umd version and set the src to path
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js

```
 <script src="path/popper.min.js"></script>
```